# In iOS dev, can you have two versions of a .nib file and compile each with its respective scheme?

Tags: ios, xcode, nib

I have a nib file for the full version of the app. Buttons in that view are connected to functions in the view's controller. I have two schemes (full version and lite version). Each one shares many files but have their own graphics files, etc. I also have #ifdef directives to include code for the lite version of the app.

I want to create another version of the nib file for the lite version because there will be slight differences in the view...color changes, an added info button, additional text, etc. The two nib files will also share a lot of the same buttons, etc. which should be connected to certain functions in the view controller.

Can I create the two nib versions and choose to include the appropriate nib in the appropriate version of my app? N.B. I want to use one Xcode project with two schemes to handle this. I don't want to maintain two separate projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can definitely do this just create two xib files and specifiy file owner of the xib to your view contorller and now you can use `initWithNibName:` to initialize your specific xib.

```
NSString *DemoViewController_xib = @"DemoViewController_FullVersion";
if (IS_Lite_Version)
    DemoViewController_xib = @"DemoViewController_LiteVersion";

DemoViewController *dvc = [[DemoViewController alloc] initWithNibName:DemoViewController_xib bundle:nil];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:dvc animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

Saurabh is correct, but it is better to use the precompiler when possible. So in your lite version add -DLITE_VERSION=1 to your compiler options, then add:

```
#ifdef LITE_VERSION
    NSString *DemoViewController_xib = @"DemoViewController_LiteVersion";
#else
    NSString *DemoViewController_xib = @"DemoViewController_FullVersion";
#endif
```

The benefit is that the #ifdef statement is evaluated at compile time so there is no additional instruction required at runtime.

I actually have 7 different apps that are all the same XCode project with different targets. That way when I improve the code for one app all of the other apps are automatically improved as well.